# watchOS Complication not showing as an option when customizing watch face

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

This is the first complication I have tried adding. I am adding it to a current project. I have managed to get it show up in the simulator, but not on my actual watch. It's just a SimpleImage complication so I am at a bit of a loss and I haven't found much online about this issue.

It shows under complications, but not as an option when customizing a watch face.

Here is my code below:

```
- (void)getSupportedTimeTravelDirectionsForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections directions))handler {
    //handler(nil);
    handler(CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirectionForward|CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirectionBackward);
}

- (void)getTimelineStartDateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(NSDate * __nullable date))handler {
    handler(nil);
}

- (void)getTimelineEndDateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(NSDate * __nullable date))handler {
    handler(nil);
}

- (void)getPrivacyBehaviorForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior privacyBehavior))handler {
    handler(CLKComplicationPrivacyBehaviorShowOnLockScreen);
}

#pragma mark - Timeline Population

- (void)getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry * __nullable))handler {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
    handler(nil);
}

- (void)getTimelineEntriesForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication beforeDate:(NSDate *)date limit:(NSUInteger)limit withHandler:(void(^)(NSArray<CLKComplicationTimelineEntry *> * __nullable entries))handler {
    // Call the handler with the timeline entries prior to the given date
    handler(nil);
}

- (void)getTimelineEntriesForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication afterDate:(NSDate *)date limit:(NSUInteger)limit withHandler:(void(^)(NSArray<CLKComplicationTimelineEntry *> * __nullable entries))handler {
    // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date
    handler(nil);
}

#pragma mark - Placeholder Templates

- (void)getLocalizableSampleTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTemplate * __nullable complicationTemplate))handler {
    handler(nil);
}

- (void)getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTemplate * __nullable complicationTemplate))handler {

    if (complication.family == CLKComplicationFamilyCircularSmall){

        CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallSimpleImage *template = [[CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallSimpleImage alloc] init];

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Circular"];

        template.imageProvider = [CLKImageProvider imageProviderWithOnePieceImage:img];

        handler(template);

    } else  if(complication.family == CLKComplicationFamilyModularSmall) {

        CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage *template = [[CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage alloc] init];

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Modular"];

        template.imageProvider = [CLKImageProvider imageProviderWithOnePieceImage:img];

        handler(template);

    }

}
```

Comment: "It shows under complications, but not as an option when customizing a watch face."  Is the first part of your sentence on the watch, and the second part on iPhone?  To get it to show on iPhone, check out the documentation about how to add a complication package to your iPhone app.

Comment: Sorry wasn't super clear with this. It shows up in the simulator under complications and can be added to watch faces. On the iPhone it shows under complication, but isn't available to add to a watch face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complication can be added to watchface in two ways:

1. On watch itself via force touch
2. On iPhone via Watch application in Face Gallery section

For both ways to work you should implement `get​Localizable​Sample​Template(for:​with​Handler:​)` [method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/clockkit/clkcomplicationdatasource/1650686-getlocalizablesampletemplate) which will be called once to populate kind of placeholder while user will be choosing complications from the list.

In order to make complication show up in Watch.app, you should additionally include special "[complication bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/WatchKit/AddingComplications/)" to your project. This bundle will be stored in iOS app and Watch.app will find it when it will need to populate it's Face Gallery.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this was the main issues. I did this and it still didn't show up in the watch face I was trying to add it too, but just noticed it works in another one of the watch faces, but unfortunately I can't be certain that this fixed it, but it help quite a bit.

Comment: Another couple of places to check: is desired complication family checked in watch extension target settings? Does watchface support this complication family?